# flickr.auth.getFrob by tcl (REST)

Tags: rest, tcl, flickr

I'm trying to get response from Flickr by using Flickr API but I have no idea and no examples in TCL for that.

I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

package require rest

set flickr(auth.getFrob) {
    url http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/
    req_args { api_key: }
}

rest::create_interface flickr 

puts [flickr::auth::getFrob -api_key  ea4a4134e2821898e5e31713d2ad74fd ]
```

When I execute it I get this error:

```
invalid command name "flickr::auth::getFrob"
    while executing
"flickr::auth::getFrob -api_key  ea4a4134e2821898e5e31713d2ad74fd "
invoked from within
"puts [flickr::auth::getFrob -api_key  ea4a4134e2821898e5e31713d2ad74fd ]"
    (file "./flickr.tcl" line 17)
```

=====================================

I've updated the last line of the code as proposed by [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn) to:

```
puts [flickr::auth.getFrob -api_key  ea4a4134e2821898e5e31713d2ad74fd ]
```

but still got the strange response:

```
rsp {stat fail} {{err {code 112 msg {Method "unknown" not found}} {}}}
```

when supposed something like:

```
<frob>746563215463214621</frob>
```

as described in Flickr API help:
[auth.getFrob](https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.auth.getFrob.htm)

Comment: That's a standard Tcl error message saying that the command you're trying to execute doesn't exist. In this case, the command is `flickr::auth::getFrob`. Judging by the name, that command might be provided by a `flickr` package - if you have it, you need to do `package require flickr` so that you can use the command. If you don't have a `flickr` package then you need to get one or write one yourself. I've certainly never heard of such a package. Good luck!

Comment: @nurdglaw Wrong. This commands are created by the rest api, which he tries to use.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the command name is

```
::flickr::auth.getFrob
```